# Why do my drop down menus take a full second to drop down?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm working to develop a new site and I've noticed that my menus drop down slower then those elsewhere.

The menu I'm referring to is on the top at [URL redacted]:
`Men's | Women's | Youth | Type |`

Comment: After redacting the URL, the question becomes _utterly_ meaningless.

Comment: Hollywood, this site works better if the related code is also pasted here :) that way this site can be a reference for years to come, rather than rely on the whims of individual websites to maintain old content for our sake. Thanks

Comment: generally it is frowned upon to link to your own website on this site. It is often seen as spam, even if it wasn't intended like that. You might want to read the FAQ on how to use the site, I'm sure you'll learn to appreciate the community here and take part of it in a meaningful matter. Welcome to SO

Comment: Why such a low rating? I agree not the most informed question, but a straight forward one with a simple answer. I can understand -1 maybe, but -5 (as i'm writing this)?

Comment: It looks like he had a url and it was lost after David's edit.

Answer (score 3):

Your Menu script has a default `delay` parameter of `350`.

You may want to change this parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your drop-down is being controlled by javascript, specifically menu.js, in which is a value: `delay: 350` Try adjusting this to your taste.

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you knew your way around the scripts you're using on your site.

If you look at your file in `/server/js/menu.js`, set your `delay` option to something less than 350.